# Do tornado AsyncHTTPClient fetch callbacks get called in order of request or response?

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, tornado

I'm using Tornado's AsyncHTTPClient to fetch a URL multiple times. I pass in a different callback with each request.

If I send requests A, B (with associated callbacks Callback_A and Callback_B) to a URL, but the responses come back in the opposite order B, A. Should I expect the callbacks to be called in the order of Callback_A, Callback_B or will they get called in the opposite order?

I'd like to have the callbacks called in the order of responses (so Callback_B, Callback_A). If that's not the default behavior is there a way to do that instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Callbacks are executed as soon as possible after the event for which they're waiting is complete. So, they are called in response order.

Comment: So here you expect to see Callback_B, then Callback_A? I just tested out 2 URLs, one which is far (China) and one which is near (in my intranet), in that order. The callback passed to the farther one printed first. So that seems to mean that the only order that matters is the one of the requests (i.e. the order in which the callbacks were passed to `fetch()` calls).

Comment: Callbacks are executed as soon as possible after the event for which they're waiting is complete. So, they are called in response order. If you share a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we might be able to see if you've made a mistake.

Comment: Ok I found the mistake in my code. Redid the test sending 3 fetchs to a far away server, monitored them on Wireshark and indeed the callbacks get called in the right order, which is the response order. Thanks again AJ.